# Symfony HiddenType for a DateTime object

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a simple form

```
   ->add('createDateTime', HiddenType::class)
```

Causing an error:

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

How do I work around this issue? I don't want to change the entity to return a string formatted date...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As form `inputs` require a text representation of the data, you'll need to convert the value to a string with the help of a [`DataTransformer`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). Fortunately, Symfony comes with a transformer for `DateTime` objects, you just need to add it to your form field:

```
$builder
    ->add('field') //...
    ->add('createDateTime', HiddenType::class);

$builder
    ->get('createDateTime')
    ->addModelTransformer(new DateTimeToStringTransformer());
```

You can specify [different timezones for conversion or format](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/9d40bd80f609fba8a329d22df20226fbf908ba14/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.php#L42) if you need to.